# ¿Como puedo trabajar con distintos lenguajes en un mismo proyecto?

Tags: python, django, go

¿Existen formas de poder comunicar modulos de GO en backend con vistas en Django y hacer que trabajen en conjunto para una pagina web?

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y de paso realiza el [tour], tu pregunta puede quedar cerrada debido a que es muy amplia y casi que basada en opiniones

Comment: Respuesta breve: SI, se puede. Respuesta larga: hace falta conocer muchos más detalles sobre qué hace la parte escrita en go, y cómo se comunicaría con la parte escrita en python. Puede ser tan "primitivo" como lanzar la aplicación go en otro proceso y tomar su salida estándar, o tan sofisticado como usar un sistema de mensajería o redis para enviar trabajos desde python a las aplicaciones go. También habría que manejar de forma correcta la asincronía para evitar dejar parado el hilo django mientras termina la parte go.

Comment: No habia pensado en el detalle de la asincronia, es bueno tenerlo en cuenta. Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente, la implementación que se usa en python es **CPython**, creada con lenguaje C(C++, por lo que es este lenguaje el que mejor interacciona con python.

Para usar módulos de go en CPython hay que emplear el interface de go para C (el mágico *"namespace C"* de cgo) y llamar al intérprete de python igual que si estuvieras programando en C. Esto es bastante complejo ya que, si no tienes bastante con un lenguaje, tienes que combinar tres: python, go y C. Tienes información en la [documentación estándar de python](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) y en [la de go](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/).

Es habitual ayudarse de algunas herramientas para generar el código C y/o cgo para crear los interfaces. Por ejemplo, para cgo está [gopy](https://github.com/go-python/gopy) capaz de crear extensiones python a partir de módulo go.

No obstante, no es un tema sencillo si no tienes experiencia de bajo nivel con los tres lenguajes mencionados. Mi recomendación es que busques otra manera de combinar estos dos lenguajes que no requiera programación de bajo nivel, por ejemplo creando microservicios.

Comment: Esta respuesta tiene todo lo que estaba buscando! Creo que buscaré la forma de conectarme a través de microservicios y apiREST, muchas gracias !